# Center pivot Instantied GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinates, gameobject

I have a GameObject and his child. When we view the parent, the pivot is the center between the gameobject and his child. When I cloned the gameobject, the child was destroyed but the pivot is still in same place and not replaced to the cloned active gameobject. How can I fix that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unity generally doesn’t do the kind of “pivot child averaging” you’re describing here. Is this object imported from a 3D program? If so, it’s much more likely the pivot is just not correct in the model. If it’s not a model and just a primitive, post a screenshot!

Comment: Yes the object is imported from a 3D program (obj) but his child is a button that is a object from Unity. When I cloned and scaled both of them, the pivot is the average of both of them. And then When I destroyed the child and kept the object (parent), the pivot stay in same position and not around the object.